# Uncaught (in promise) CustomPouchError ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED

Tags: pouchdb

I have a pouchDB that is syncing nicely with a hosted couchDB :

```
sync.company = db.company.sync(companyUrl, {live: true, retry: true})
```

in my app when I detect that the network is no longer available I stop the syncing:

```
if (sync.company) sync.company.cancel();
```

when the network comes back up again later, my first step is to find out the latest update sequence from the remote host :

```
PouchDB(companyUrl).info().then(function (info) {... <--uncaught error!
```

but this is throwing the following error :

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
  39.EventEmitter.removeAllListeners    
  (anonymous function)  
  39.EventEmitter.emit  
  39.EventEmitter.removeListener    
  (anonymous function)  
  39.EventEmitter.emit  
  39.EventEmitter.removeListener    
  39.EventEmitter.removeAllListeners    
  39.EventEmitter.removeAllListeners    
  (anonymous function)
OPTIONS <URL>/?_nonce=2isvTJGAXQtX9HWD net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
  ajax  
  ajax  
  HttpPouch 
  (anonymous function)  
  PouchDB   
  PouchDB   
  startSync 
  (anonymous function)  
  $get.Scope.$digest    
  $get.Scope.$apply 
  (anonymous function)  
Uncaught (in promise) CustomPouchError
```

it all seems to start at line 10534 of pouchdb.js:

```
if (isFunction(listeners)) {
    this.removeListener(type, listeners);
  } else {
    // LIFO order
    while (listeners.length)  <------!!!!!!!! error starts here !!!!!
      this.removeListener(type, listeners[listeners.length - 1]);
  }
  delete this._events[type];
```

what does it mean ??

I am using pouchdb 3.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug in PouchDB and it's fixed in master. In particular, it was fixed by [this commit](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/commit/f83e0e3b62fc7d4e28669fc128f3228d082d2d94).

If you want to live on the bleeding edge, you can build PouchDB from source and use that:

```
git clone https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb && cd pouchdb && npm install && npm run build
```

Or wait for the next release. :)